# Create GET parameter from xml array

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm new to `WSO2 EI`.
Now I already create a `rest API,` and in in_sequense I call first `WSDL` endpoint with parameters from created API and I retrieve next XML from this `WSDL` endpoint.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://pse/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:dl190Response>
         <mvts>
            <mvts_S>
               <x>x1</x>
               <w>w1</w>
            </mvts_S>
            <mvts_S>
               <x>x2</x>
               <w>w2</w>
            </mvts_S>
         </mvts>
      </ns1:dl190Response>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can I create a parameter with value `"Your statistic is x1, w1, x2, w2"` to call the next endpoint with get parameters?
XML array from the first endpoint can be with different weight.
Which mediators can I use for it?
Thank you!

Comment: Could you describe in a muh better way, all i understood was that you need to call multiple endpoints in a sequential manner however may i know what do you want to do after calling WSDL endpoints.Do you want to frame a request from the response of the previous call and then call another wsdl endpoint ?

Comment: Hi thank you for quick reaction. I want to put all value from             <mvts_S>
               <x>x1</x>
               <w>w1</w>
            </mvts_S>
            <mvts_S>
               <x>x2</x>
               <w>w2</w>
            </mvts_S> tags in to one parameters. The value of new parameters must be "Your statistic is x1, w1, x2, w2" and call another rest endpoint, not wsdl endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood that your requirement is to fetch the values from the XML and store it in a variable so that you can use this value to call something else, if this understanding is correct you can use xpath to fetch the values and store them in a property and you can use the property later on.

```
 <property name="yourParameter" expression="concat('Your statistic ',$body//*[local-name()='mvts_S'][1]/*[local-name()='x'],',',$body//*[local-name()='mvts_S'][1]/*[local-name()='w'],',',$body//*[local-name()='mvts_S'][2]/*[local-name()='x'],',',$body//*[local-name()='mvts_S'][2]/*[local-name()='w'])"/>
<log level="custom">
                <property name="yourParameter" expression="$ctx:yourParameter"/>
             </log>
```

Above only works if there are fixed array, however for multiple elements in array you need to write xslt mediator and then output of that needs to be concatenated in property.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
 <Root>          
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='dl190Response']/*[local-name()='mvts']/*[local-name()='mvts_S']">

           <xsl:value-of select="concat(x,',')"/><xsl:value-of select="concat(w,',')"/>

    </xsl:for-each>
</Root> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After xslt mediator use property mediator

```
   <log level="custom">
            <property name="yourParameter" expression=" concat ('Your statistic ',$body//*[local-name()='Root']/text())"/>
         </log>
         <property name="yourParameter" expression=" concat ('Your statistic ',$body//*[local-name()='Root']/text())"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="yourParameter1" expression="substring($ctx:yourParameter,1,string-length($ctx:yourParameter)-1)"/>
         </log>
```

Comment: You understand my request correctly, but the xml array can be any length. What xpath will be in this case? I mean that the  [1] and [2] from your xpath, does not always fit in my case

Comment: Could you please accept the answer so that it can be helpful for others